# How to get an element using c#

Tags: c#, html, web-scraping

I'm new with C#, and I'm trying to access an element from a website using webBrowser. I wondered how can I get the "Developers" string from the site:

`<div id="title" style="display: block;">
 <b>Title:</b> **Developers**
 </div>`

I tried to use `webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("title")` ,but I have no idea how to keep going from here.

Thanks :)

Comment: Have a look at http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: ... or [CsQuery](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery) if you know jQuery

Answer (score 0):

You can download the source code using [WebClient class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx)

then look within the file for the `<b>Title:</b>**Developers**</div>` and then omit everything beside the "Developers".

Answer (score 0):

You can use HtmlAgilityPack (As mentioned by Giannis http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). Using a web browser control is too much for this task:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("http://www.google.com");

var el = doc.GetElementbyId("title");
string s = el.InnerHtml; // get the : <b>Title:</b> **Developers**
```

I haven't tried this code but it should be very close to working.

There must be an `InnerText` in HtmlAgilityPack as well, allowing you to do this:

```
string s = el.InnerText; // get the : Title: **Developers**
```

You can also remove the `Title:` by removing the appropriate node:

```
el.SelectSingleNode("//b").Remove();
string s = el.InnerText; // get the : **Developers**
```

---

If for some reason you want to stick to the web browser control, I think you can do this:

```
var el = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("title");
string s = el.InnerText; // get the : Title: **Developers**
```

---

**UPDATE**
Note that the `//b` above is XPath syntax which may be interesting for you to learn:

http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/xpath_syntax.asp

http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html

Comment: side note, `el.InnerText` return concatenated text of all text nodes within the `<div>`, in this case : "*Title: Developers*"

Comment: @har07 Yes, I have just corrected it while reviewing my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

`HtmlAgilityPack` and `CsQuery` is the way many people has taken to work with HTML page in .NET, I'd recommend them too.

But in case your task is limited to this simple requirement, and you have a `<div>` markup that is valid XHTML (like the markup sample you posted), then you can treat it as an XML. Means you can use .NET native API such as `XDocument` or `XmlDocument` to parse the HTML and perform an XPath query to get specific part from it, for example :

```
var xml = @"<div id=""title"" style=""display: block;""> <b>Title:</b> Developers</div>";
//or according to your code snippet, you may be able to do as follow :
//var xml = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("title").OuterHtml;

var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
var text = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//div/b/following-sibling::text()");
Console.WriteLine(text.InnerText);
//above prints " Developers"
```

Above XPath select text node (`"Developers"`) next to `<b>` node.